# "Bad usage of mount"

Tags: linux, mount, vmware

I'm running a SIFT workstation appliance in VMware (latest and greatest). I'm trying to mount a dd image and keep getting an error.

```
mount –o loop,ro,show_sys_files,streams_interface=windows 001.dd /mnt/windows_mount
```

mount: bad usage

I'm running Terminal from the location in which the image is stored, which is a shared folder from Windows. I've also tried running mount with no options whatseover, just this command:

```
mount 001.dd /mnt/windows_mount
```

That results in this error: *Cannot mount 001.d read-only*.

As a last-ditch attempt, I'm copying the image over to the VM so I won't be dealing with a Windows share, but I'm really curious as to why I can't mount this image. Any ideas?

TIA!

Chop